# ioncube not working with php-fpm nginx

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm, ioncube

php version:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Steps i did:

1. Downloaded:
   http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
2. Placed compatible loaders under /usr/lib/php5/20121212
3. Created config under: /etc/php5/mods-available/ioncube.conf:

zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so

4. Created symlink: ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/ioncube.ini /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/

restarted php-fpm and nginx, but phpinfo() and php -v still not showing this damn ioncube. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with php-fpm bug in Ubuntu.

Had to do the following:

```
service php5-fpm stop
ps aux | grep php
kill (ID's of PHP processes)
service php5-fpm start
```

I just had to reload php-fpm